# Command to show difference between a buffer and its corresponding file

Tags: emacs, diff

Is there an emacs command to show the difference between a buffer and its file?

For example, I've made some edits to a buffer, forgotten what they were, and now I need to save the buffer to its file, but want to check what I have actually changed first.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`diff-buffer-with-file`. I just googled for "emacs compare buffer file changed".

Comment: And the ediff version is: `M-x ediff-current-file`

Comment: Bing brought me here for "emacs diff buffer with file on disk"

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to hit `C-x s` followed by `d`. This also shows a diff between a buffer and its file.

Most useful if the buffer of interest is the only one that needs saving.

Comment: This won't work if the file has changed and the buffer hasn't (through, for example, version control shenanigans). Emacs will just say "no changes need to be saved".